# Disable Varnish headers (and other headers)?

Tags: php, apache, caching, header, varnish

I'm trying to minimize the headers my server sends. Ideally, it would only send the absolute minimum (<4 headers).

Right now it's sending these:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
disablevcache: true
Content-Type: 
Content-Length: 5
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 25 Sep 2013 03:58:06 GMT
X-Varnish: 650927475
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
```

Anyone know of ways I can disable more of these from inside PHP, or decrease the size (every byte helps in this situation)? remove_header's only got rid of one.

Comment: You can actually get rid of most of them with PHP, but they are only removed for the web server running PHP behind it. Varnish will add headers as it sees fits, which can be removed via the `vcl_deliver` subroutine.

Comment: I'm confused- What do you mean they are only removed for the web server? Also I found this subroutine stuff while googling but I'm not sure what it means, don't I need access to the server for this, because I'm on shared hosting.

Comment: Varnish is a layer on top of a web server such as apache or nginx. When you use `remove_header()`, it will remove the header for the request exiting your web server. Varnish (who actually originates the request), will rewrite the HTTP request as it sees fit and add headers. It's unfortunate that you're on shared hosting... I don't see them allowing you to edit your varnish configuration.

Comment: They tend not to let me do much. However, it looks like only 3 of the headers are Varnish related, so any tips on removing the other headers?

Comment: Varnish is actually spitting out all the headers (including the ones you've unset in PHP). It's trying to do things like cache control and make things faster for a browser viewing the result in the request. The easiest way is to disable varnish... with headers you send from PHP. I believe `Pragma: no-cache` will turn it off. If not, you have to add an additional `Cache-Control` header.

Comment: I set both of those headers first thing in my script to "no-cache", but I still get the Varnish headers.